# NuPIC one_hot_gym tutorial swarm attribute error

Tags: python, nupic

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at:

https://github.com/numenta/nupic/tree/master/examples/opf/clients/hotgym/prediction/one_gym

I'm right at the beginning but running the very first python script gave me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "swarm.py", line 105, in <module>
    swarm(INPUT_FILE)
  File "swarm.py", line 97, in swarm
    modelParams = swarmForBestModelParams(SWARM_DESCRIPTION, name)
  File "swarm.py", line 68, in swarmForBestModelParams
    modelParams = permutations_runner.runWithConfig(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'runWithConfig'
```

So I don't see anyone else complaining about this error so I'm assuming its something I'm doing (or overlooking) can you help me understand whats going on?

The contents of swarm.py are here:

https://github.com/numenta/nupic/blob/master/examples/opf/clients/hotgym/prediction/one_gym/swarm.py

Comment: I found a related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690772/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute 
Could my issue be circular imports like his?

Comment: I checked the permutations_runner.py and it does have a def runWithConfig but I couldn't tell if it was passing data to it correctly. could that cause the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you probably cloned NuPIC before you watched and ran the tutorial. The tutorial requires you to have the latest codebase. Pull the latest from master, rebuild NuPIC and try it again.

Even if you've updated the codebase and you can see the `runWithConfig` function, you will still need to re-run the build process as described in the `README.md`.