# SyntaxError: 'return' outside function?

Tags: python

I want to return 2 values : the first one is data read from sensor connected to raspberry and the second one is current time

rasp.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
class ReturnValue(object):
  __slots__ = ["x","y"]
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def foo ( ) :
  i = 0 
  for i in range(0,19):
     i += 1
     tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000007101990/w1_slave")
     text = tfile.read()
     tfile.close()
     secondline = text.split("\n")[1]
     temp = secondline.split(" ")[9]
     temperature  = float(temp[2:])
     temperature = temperature/1000
     mystr = str(temperature)
     y =  mystr.replace(",",".")
     x = datetime.datetime.now().time() 
return  ReturnValue(x, y)
```

Comment: The `return` statement is clearly outside of the `foo` function. In Python indentation matters.

You also don't need to create a class in order to return two objects. Simply do `return x, y`.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/  read this link

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime

Comment: `datetime.now()` is correct because we imported `datetime` from `datetime`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't properly indent your `return` statement and also the first line in the function `foo`.

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690772/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute